# Jqgrid - how to reload JQgrid data with new data output based on user form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have created a search box, which the user enters a name or id in the search form input box and it returns the result . Only problem it works only once.

Here is my HTML below

```
  <button id="basic-search" class="btn btn-default " type="button" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>

    <input type="text" id="basicsearchVal" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text,." autocomplete="on">
```

I then pass the entered value "**searchInput**" as a querystring url to the jQgrid

```
var searchInput = $("#basicsearchVal").val()

SearchData =newURL +"/services-monitor/GetQuickSearch?searchString="+searchInput;
```

When the user searches, it return the result the first time. but when I try to enter a new name or number in the search form box second time, the jqgrid doesnt seem to update the result, it just show the old result, even though i can see the updated user submitted value is being passed correctly to the JQgrid ajax call.

Only if I refresh the page manually every time it return the result

I also added this as per examples online.:

```
$(".search-result").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
jQuery(".search-result").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

what can I do to fix this? why wont JQgrid reload and display the updated results?

Here my JS CODE and [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m3n5fbbd/6/)

```
 var jsonData = [{
   "Id": 919,
   "CertificateNumber": "4829",
   "Name": "1880 Bank",
   "FullName": "1880 Bank",
   "address": "304 HIGH STREET",
   "city": "CAMBRIDGE",
   "state": "MD",
   "zip": "21613"

 }, {
   "Id": 6020,
   "CertificateNumber": "57899",
   "Name": "1st Advantage Bank",
   "FullName": "1st Advantage Bank",
   "address": "240 SALT LICK ROAD",
   "city": "SAINT PETERS",
   "state": "MO",
   "zip": "63376"

 }, {
   "Id": 3817,
   "CertificateNumber": "22039",
   "Name": "1st Bank",
   "FullName": "1st Bank",
   "address": "201 NORTH WILBUR AVE",
   "city": "BROADUS",
   "state": "MT",
   "zip": "59317"
 }, {
   "Id": 3054,
   "CertificateNumber": "16419",
   "Name": "1st Bank & Trust",
   "FullName": "1st Bank & Trust",
   "address": "710 SOUTH PARK DRIVE",
   "city": "BROKEN BOW",
   "state": "OK",
   "zip": "74728"
 }, {
   "Id": 4843,
   "CertificateNumber": "30367",
   "Name": "1st Bank of Sea Isle City",
   "FullName": "1st Bank of Sea Isle City",
   "address": "4301 LANDIS AVENUE",
   "city": "SEA ISLE CITY",
   "state": "NJ",
   "zip": "08243"
 }, {
   "Id": 5817,
   "CertificateNumber": "57298",
   "Name": "1st Bank Yuma",
   "FullName": "1st Bank Yuma",
   "address": "2799 SOUTH 4TH AVENUE",
   "city": "YUMA",
   "state": "AZ",
   "zip": "85364"
 }, {
   "Id": 5031,
   "CertificateNumber": "32487",
   "Name": "1st Cameron State Bank",
   "FullName": "1st Cameron State Bank",
   "address": "124 SOUTH WALNUT",
   "city": "CAMERON",
   "state": "MO",
   "zip": "64429"
 }, {
   "Id": 6278,
   "CertificateNumber": "58485",
   "Name": "1st Capital Bank",
   "FullName": "1st Capital Bank",
   "address": "5 HARRIS COURT, BLDG N, # NO",
   "city": "MONTEREY",
   "state": "CA",
   "zip": "93940"
 }, {
   "Id": 5942,
   "CertificateNumber": "57657",
   "Name": "1st Century Bank,  National Association",
   "FullName": "1st Century Bank,  National Association",
   "address": "1875 CENTURY PARK EAST, # 14",
   "city": "LOS ANGELES",
   "state": "CA",
   "zip": "90067"
 }, {
   "Id": 5666,
   "CertificateNumber": "35456",
   "Name": "1st Colonial Community Bank",
   "FullName": "1st Colonial Community Bank",
   "address": "1040 HADDON AVENUE",
   "city": "COLLINGSWOOD",
   "state": "NJ",
   "zip": "08108"
 }, {
   "Id": 2116,
   "CertificateNumber": "11706",
   "Name": "1st Community Bank",
   "FullName": "1st Community Bank",
   "address": "407 THIRD STREET",
   "city": "SHERRARD",
   "state": "IL",
   "zip": "61281"
 }, {
   "Id": 4381,
   "CertificateNumber": "27552",
   "Name": "1st Constitution Bank",
   "FullName": "1st Constitution Bank",
   "address": "2650 ROUTE 130",
   "city": "CRANBURY",
   "state": "NJ",
   "zip": "08512"
 }, {
   "Id": 5327,
   "CertificateNumber": "34393",
   "Name": "1st Equity Bank",
   "FullName": "1st Equity Bank",
   "address": "3956 WEST DEMPSTER STREET",
   "city": "SKOKIE",
   "state": "IL",
   "zip": "60076"
 }, {
   "Id": 5928,
   "CertificateNumber": "57611",
   "Name": "1st Equity Bank Northwest",
   "FullName": "1st Equity Bank Northwest",
   "address": "1330 DUNDEE ROAD",
   "city": "BUFFALO GROVE",
   "state": "IL",
   "zip": "60089"
 }, {
   "Id": 326,
   "CertificateNumber": "1673",
   "Name": "1st Financial Bank USA",
   "FullName": "1st Financial Bank USA",
   "address": "331 N. DAKOTA DUNES BLVD.",
   "city": "DAKOTA DUNES",
   "state": "SD",
   "zip": "57049"
 }, {
   "Id": 6307,
   "CertificateNumber": "58548",
   "Name": "1st Manatee Bank",
   "FullName": "1st Manatee Bank",
   "address": "12215 US HIGHWAY 301 N",
   "city": "PARRISH",
   "state": "FL",
   "zip": "34219"
 }, {
   "Id": 1220,
   "CertificateNumber": "6646",
   "Name": "1st National Bank",
   "FullName": "1st National Bank",
   "address": "730 EAST MAIN STREET",
   "city": "LEBANON",
   "state": "OH",
   "zip": "45036"
 }, {
   "Id": 647,
   "CertificateNumber": "3564",
   "Name": "1st National Bank of South Florida",
   "FullName": "1st National Bank of South Florida",
   "address": "1550 NORTH KROME AVENUE",
   "city": "HOMESTEAD",
   "state": "FL",
   "zip": "33030"
 }];
```

JQGRID code

```
        window.makeSearchGridAjaxCall = function(detailPageUrl, SearchData, jsondata) {
           console.log(" SearchData " + SearchData);
           $(".search-result").jqGrid({
             url: SearchData,
             /**url: "/echo/json/", */
             mtype: "POST",
             // data: mydata,
             datatype: "json",
             emptyrecords: "0 records found",
             postData: {
               json: JSON.stringify(jsondata)
             },
             success: function(mydata, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               console.log(" data :" + mydata);
               console.log(" data :" + bmUSearchData);
             },
             colModel: [

               {
                 name: 'Id',
                 label: ' Id',
                 align: 'left',
                 width: 20,
                 hidden: true
               }, {
                 name: 'CertificateNumber',
                 label: 'Cert #',
                 align: 'center',
                 width: 30,
                 search: true,
                 key: true,
                 formatter: "showlink",
                 formatoptions: {
                   baseLinkUrl: detailPageUrl,
                   idName: "",
                   addParam: function(options) {
                     return "bankid=" + options.rowData.bankId + "";
                   }
                 }

               },

               {
                 name: 'address',
                 label: 'Address',
                 align: 'left',
                 width: 85,
                 search: false
               }, {
                 name: 'city',
                 label: 'City',
                 align: 'left',
                 width: 50,
                 search: false
               }, {
                 name: 'state',
                 label: 'State',
                 align: 'left',
                 width: 20,
                 search: true
               }, {
                 name: 'zip',
                 label: 'Zip',
                 align: 'right',
                 width: 25,
                 search: false
               },

             ],
             additionalProperties: ["address", "city", "state", "zip"],
             subGrid: true,
             subGridRowExpanded: function(subgridDivId, rowid) {
               var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);
               $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId)).html("<div class=\"col-md-1\"><b>Address: </b></div>" + item.address +
                 "<br/><div class=\"col-md-1\"><b>City: </b></div>" + item.city + "<br><div class=\"col-md-1\"> <b>Zip: </b></div>" + item.zip + "");
             },

             iconSet: "fontAwesome",
             loadonce: true,
       **navOptions: { reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true } },**
             rownumbers: true,
             cmTemplate: {
               autoResizable: true,
               editable: true
             },
             autoResizing: {
               compact: true
             },
             forceClientSorting: true,
             sortname: "Symbol",
             height: "auto",
             caption: "<b>Watch List</b>",
             viewrecords: true,
             autowidth: true, // set 'true' here
             shrinkToFit: true, // well, it's 'true' by default


             loadError: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
                 $errorDiv = $(this.grid.eDiv),
                 $errorSpan = $errorDiv.children(".ui-jqgrid-error");

               $errorSpan.html("No Data Available");
               $errorDiv.show();
               if (p.errorDisplayTimeout) {
                 setTimeout(function() {
                   $errorSpan.empty();
                   $errorDiv.hide();
                 }, p.errorDisplayTimeout);
               }
             },



           });

           $(".search-result").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
             stringResult: true,
             searchOnEnter: false,
             defaultSearch: "cn"
           });


           $(window).resize(function() {
             var outerwidth = $('#grid').width();
             $('.search-result').setGridWidth(outerwidth); // setGridWidth method sets a new width to the grid dynamically
           });


           /************************************************************************************/
         }


         $(document).ready(function() {

           var newURL;
           var SearchData;

           if (document.location.hostname == "localhost") {
             newURL = "http://localhost:8080";
           } else {
             newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
           }
           console.log("URL " + newURL);
           var detailPageUrl = "bm_summary_tpl.html";
           //var prodUrl ="";    
           var mydata;

           $("#basic-search").click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var searchInput = $("#basicsearchVal").val()
             if ($('input:text').val().length == 0) {
               alert("Searched clicked  and text is empty" + searchInput)
             } else {
               alert("go to search page " + $('input:text').val());
               console.log("SearchData " + SearchData);
               $(".search-result").load();

               //search-result
               console.log(" +searchInput " + searchInput);
               SearchData = newURL + "/services-monitor/GetQuickSearch?searchString=" + searchInput;
               console.log("bmSearchData " + SearchData);
               makeSearchGridAjaxCall(detailPageUrl, SearchData, mydata);
$(".search-result").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                    jQuery(".search-result").trigger("reloadGrid");
               $("#basicsearchVal").val("");

             }

           });

         })
```

;

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution

at first i tried these 2 , which didnt work in my case.

```
$("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
$("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", { fromServer: true, page: 1 });
```

I applied this which worked like a charm, it clear the grid and reload data every time the user searches new data

```
        $(".search-result").jqGrid('GridUnload');
        var searchInput = $("#basicsearchVal").val()
        if ($('input:text').val().length == 0) {
             alert("Please enter a Name to search")
        }
        else {

            $( "#watchlist-b").remove();
             $("#watchList-b1").remove();
             $("#watchList-b2").remove();

                SearchData =newURL +"/services-monitor/GetQuickSearch?searchString="+searchInput;

                makeSearchGridAjaxCall (detailPageUrl,SearchData,mydata); 
                jQuery(".search-result").trigger("reloadGrid");
```